# Patient suffering from X disease vs controls

Tags: disease

I'm reading a paper where I encountered the following sentence: "the difference between patients suffering from x disease vs controls was ... ". What does controls mean?

Comment: Control refers to a [control group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treatment_and_control_groups).